# Browser always sends the "noSelection" value of the Grails <g:select> tag library

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.2

I have this select input in my gsp:

```
<g:select id="whitelistId" name="whitelistId" noSelection="${['nx':'-Select whitelist-']}" from="${Whitelist.list()}" optionValue="description" optionKey="id" />
```

Even if I change to another item in the dropdown, "nx" value is being sent as params value. If I omit `noSelection` attribute, it works as expected.

This is the generated html code when "My whitelist" item is selected:

```
<select id="whitelistId" name="whitelistId">
  <option value="nx">-Select whitelist-</option>
  <option value="6118854">My whitelist</option>
</select>
```

I'm using Grails 2.2.0

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the generated html code of `<g:select />`? What Grails version do you use?

Comment: Sorry guys, there was an issue in my code. It's all working OK now.

Answer (score 1):

[ref-doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html) states:

> Typically this will be blank - but you can also use 'null' in the case that you're passing the ID of an object

so, it's better to use

> noSelection="${['':'-Select whitelist-']}"

or

> noSelection="${[null:'-Select whitelist-']}"